# What mathematical expressions took a long time for a closed form to be found?

Tags: mathematics

The [Basel problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{n^2}}$, took 90 years for a closed form, $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, to be found.

I'm curious to know what other mathematical expressions, especially those involving limits, took a long time for a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) to be found. (By "found", I mean discovered and verified.)

Comment: [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) for the roots of a cubic. It is hard to say when the idea of a closed form algebraic solution was first conceived, but Omar Khayyam already talked of its desirability c. 1100. The formula was only derived c. 1540.

Comment: In more recent times, one of Ramanujan's closed form expressions for a series from his lost notebook (written in 1919-20) was only proved in 2019 by [Berndt, Li, and Zaharescu](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/jlms.12228), see (1.10). In fairness, the notebook was only found in 1976.

Answer (score 7):

[Euler's Pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) was discovered by Euler in 1775, published in 1783. In his paper Euler gave only heuristic arguments. The first
rigorous proof
[was obtained by Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) in 1829.

The theorem is an identity for formal series:
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty(-1)^nx^{n(3n-1)/2}.$$

Comment: I am guessing that this was in his _Fundamenta Nova_. Please give the page number?